# Sort multiple array with data from ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort a 2d array that contains data I get from an ajax query but it doesn't sort it anymore.

So to be clear, responseAccident is an array containing value from a `COUNT` query, I merge the two arrays into one 2d array and then I'm trying to sort it but I really can't do it, the values that the alert showed me are not sorted anymore.

So this is my code :

```
var arrayCityAccident = [];
for (var i = 0; i < responseAccident.length; i++) {
    arrayCityAccident.push([responseCity[i]['city'], parseInt(responseAccident[i])]);
}
arrayCityAccident.sort(compareSecondColumn);
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    alert(arrayCityAccident[i][0] + " " + arrayCityAccident[i][1]);
}
```

And the sort function :

```
function compareSecondColumn(a, b)
{
    return parseInt(a[1]) < parseInt(b[1]);
}
```

If someone could help that would be great ! Thank's in advance !

Comment: Instead of `alert` use `console.log` and use this before push insert. That way (at least in Chrome) you can see exactly what you're inserting. Then do the same in your sort function.

Comment: I know what I've insert, I already have look at what I've insert and the data are good but this is the result I have from the 10 alert (or console.log) I made after the sorting function :

Saldus 4 
Riga 900 
Marupe 3 
Jurmala 29 
Vilani 1 
Koknese 3 
Berzkrogs 4 
Grobina 3 
Baltezers 8 
Iecava 7 

So you can see that it's not sorted. :/

Comment: `alert` will display string output. `console.log(item)` will allow you to interact with item as an object or array in the console. Then it becomes easier to see if you are referencing the array items correctly. It will also help to make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).